# Is there any application for handling groups and members on Linux?

Tags: php, linux, security

I have a Linux production server.

There are no simple codes for viewing groups, members, how many groups one member is part of etc etc.

Is there any good and secure application for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do of course have the command line tools.

Finding out which groups alice is memeber of:

```
groups alice
```

Getting a list of all groups:

```
cut -f1 -d: /etc/group
```

Getting a list of all users and which groups they are members of:

```
for user in `cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd`; do groups $user; done
```

Everything is possible :)

Answer (score 1):

Webmin can completely manage a server, it also does virtual and web hosting servers. [Webmin.com](http://webmin.com). It provides a nice SSL supported web interface too.

Comment: Too advanced... something simple, on the terminal... Dont need any interface

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is available on your system, but you could try `/usr/bin/system-config-users`

Comment: Not available...

Answer (score 0):

it depends what distro you use.

There is getent which can do things like that. Otherwise with little perl or shell scripting knowledge, that's easily doable.